# Best practice using RecyclerView, ListAdapter and ViewModel for saving checked status

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am using RecyclerView with [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) which using [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.html) internally to show the data. Of course, all the data was provided by ViewModel via `LiveData`.

Now each item view has a CheckBox, meanwhile I implemented drag selection function by adding `RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener`. Selection status is now maintained by the adapter, it is not a good idea since status will lost after screen rotation.

I want to let ViewModel save the selection status and it is my idea:

1. Fragment will call the ViewModel to change the status when receiving the relevant callback.
2. ViewModel will change the data list (or create a new one if it is not mutable) and post to LiveData.
3. Fragment receives the data change and submits it to `ListAdapter`.

The problem is that the selection status can change very frequently if user acitvate drag selection. `DifferUtil` has to spend a long time comparing if there are a lot of data. Unlike saving status inside the adapter, now I cannot notify item changed accurately because I don't know which position is changed.

The core idea of MVVM is data-driven view, but in this case we lost additional information(e.g. position) causing extra calculations. So what is the best practice?

Part of the adapter code (based on `GroupListAdapter` which extend `ListAdapter`):

```
    private val selectedGroups = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    private val selectedImages = mutableSetOf<Image>()

    override fun onBindGroupViewHolder(holder: StubViewHolder, groupIndex: Int, flattedPosition: Int) {
        holder.setText(R.id.itemImageTitleTextView, getGroupItem(groupIndex).title)
    }

    override fun onBindChildViewHolder(holder: StubViewHolder, groupIndex: Int, childIndex: Int, flattedPosition: Int) {
        val data = getChildItem(groupIndex, childIndex)
        GlideApp.with(fragment).load(data.uri).into(holder.getView(R.id.itemImageView))
    }

    override fun onBindGroupViewHolder(holder: StubViewHolder, groupIndex: Int, flattedPosition: Int,
                                       payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        holder.setGroupSelectionMode(isInSelectMode())
        holder.setGroupChecked(selectedGroups.contains(flattedPosition))
    }

    override fun onBindChildViewHolder(holder: StubViewHolder, groupIndex: Int, childIndex: Int, flattedPosition: Int,
                                       payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        if (isInSelectMode()) {
            holder.setImageSelectionMode(true)
            if (selectedImages.contains(getItem(flattedPosition))) {
                holder.getView<MaskImageView>(R.id.itemImageView).isChecked = true
                holder.setImageChecked(true)
            } else {
                holder.getView<MaskImageView>(R.id.itemImageView).isChecked = false
                holder.setImageChecked(false)
            }
        } else {
            holder.getView<MaskImageView>(R.id.itemImageView).isChecked = false
            holder.setImageSelectionMode(false)
        }
    }

    fun setSelected(position: Int, isSelected: Boolean, refreshItem: Boolean = true) {
        if (!isChildItem(position)) {
            return
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            selectedImages.add(getItem(position) as Image)
        } else {
            selectedImages.remove(getItem(position))
        }
        if (refreshItem) {
            notifyItemChanged(position, true)
        }
        onSelectChangedCallback?.invoke(selectedImages.size)
    }
```

Comment: This is interesting. Please post your adapter? RecyclerView normally renders not full set of data, just what fits the screen plus some extra. Also, what is the volume of data we speak of?

Comment: @ror I have added some codes but I think adapter is not important. That is true only visible item will be rendered, but the problem is `DiffUtil` will compare the entire data list to calculate the difference. There are about 1,000~4,000 items, since this application will run on watch devices, this size is not small anymore.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm mistaken, but looks like you are not using paging? Depending on your data nature, you could use any descendant datasources of https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/DataSource.html. Your DiffUtils would then operate on much smaller subset of data. You could offset selected items (I'm assuming it can be more then one) to viewmodel, keep them as state, and even dynamically wrap your original data into some wrapper that has indication of selection - inside datasource itself. Thus your adapter would be purely data driven.

Comment: Some questions: 1. Paging do not support modify the data after it was loaded. 2. Because of 1, I have to use another variable to save state, that means I still maintain the state between data and view - no data driven. 3. In addition to 1, even if use paging, data will be bigger and bigger. Suppose the user loads 10 pages, each submission is still compared to the overall comparison.(That is [way paging do not support modification](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/281#issuecomment-399732392))

Comment: But inspired by you, I save the selected items to ViewModle when `onDestroy`, and restore it when UI is recreated. It is not data-driven pattern but does solve the  problem. I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Chenhe you're of course right re immutability, but you're performing selection in page visible to the user, correct? Which basically means to me I could load that same page as a first action on new pageable list? (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource#updating-paged-data)

Comment: This seems to work. However migration to Paging is a big project since I have other features such as Group(selection), FastScroll, TotalCount etc. Maybe Paging will break them. In fact what I am building is somethig like Google Photos - an gallery application. I will try this solution later. Thanks for such unique idea.